# Accessing the VALUE behind a CheckListBox in a ForEach or For Loop

Tags: c#

I have a loop that pads out a `CheckListBox` with Values (for display) and an internal key.

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (RAPID_Designer.DWPerspective dataRow in bsPerspective)
        {
            dict.Add(dataRow.DWPerspectiveId, dataRow.DWPerspectiveName);

        }
        checkListPerspectives.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
        checkListPerspectives.DisplayMember = "Value";
        checkListPerspectives.ValueMember = "Key";
```

I subsequently want to loop through all the entries in the `CheckListBox` and determine whether or not to `autotick` them for the user.

But I can't figure out a way of accessing the "Key" value in a `ForEach` loop.  I need to check each key in the list so I can determine from other sources whether or not to automatically tick the value.

I've tried casting as `Dictionary` and `DictionaryEntry` etc, but nothing seems to let me at the key value - which I can even see on hoverhints while debugging.

`PerspectiveId` is the `Key` field and an `integer`.
`PerspectiveName` is the `Value` field, a nice string for users to read.
Help?

Comment: Cant you try foreach(ListIem lstItem in checkListPerspectives.Items)

Comment: ListItem didnt seem to work.  What I had to do was change the original declaration to not use a New Binding source, but connect to a new list of DWPerspective (which had the keys already) and then case the items as (DWPerspective).  At this point I am then able to access the items of DWPerspective, which means I have not only the keys, but all the related properties - so this is much more powerful than what I was trying.